# Multiple kube-schedulers

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a kube-shceduler that will be used by my organisation pod deployment (a data-center). The objective would be to have the pods of any deployment be split equally between the two sites of the data-center.
To archive this I created a new kube-shceduler manifest (see below), in which i changed the Ports that are used and added a new configuration file (see below) using the `--config` parameter.
The problem is that even after setting the `--port` parameter to a new port that isn't already used by the original kube-scheduler, it still tries to use the old one. As such the new kube scheduler can't start:

```
I1109 20:27:59.225996       1 registry.go:173] Registering SelectorSpread plugin
I1109 20:27:59.226097       1 registry.go:173] Registering SelectorSpread plugin
I1109 20:27:59.926994       1 serving.go:331] Generated self-signed cert in-memory
failed to create listener: failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:10251: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:10251: bind: address already in use
```

How can I force the use of the specified port OR how can I delete the original kube-scheduler so that there won't be any conflict between the two. The first solution would be preferable.

Configuration kube-scheduler (manifest - /etc/kubernetes/manifest/kube-scheduler.yaml) :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=true
      #- --port=0
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.19.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10259
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-scheduler
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10259
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
status: {}
```

Configuration kube-custom-scheduler.yaml (/etc/kubernetes/manifest/kube-custom-scheduler.yaml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-custom-scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-custom-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler 
    - --config=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf
    - --master=true
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=false
    - --secure-port=10269
    - --scheduler-name=kube-custom-shceduler
    - --port=10261
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.19.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10269
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-scheduler
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10269
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf
      name: customconfig
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: customconfig 
status: {}
```

Custom configuration mentioned in the kube-custom-scheduler.yaml (/etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf):

```
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration

profiles:
  - pluginConfig:
      - name: PodTopologySpread
        args:
          defaultConstraints:
            - maxSkew: 1
              topologyKey: topology.kube.io/datacenter 
              whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
```

Please don't hesitate if you need more information about the cluster.

PS:
As of today I couldn't get the overwrite of the default (insecure) port to work. I moved to a different alternative to archive the goal. I created an Admission Controller (Kyverno) that will mutate the Deployment/Pods files by adding the "podtopologyspread" field to every deployment. So now every pod that's deployed will assigned to one of the two sites existent in the data-center according to the rules defined by the Admission Controller.
If anyone has succeeded to change the configuration of the default Kube-Scheduller I would love to know how you did it.

Comment: Did you notice the topology feature of the native kube-scheduler? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode

Comment: Consider to read the following documentation if you still want to deploy another scheduler. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/), `--port` flag has already been deprecated, so chances are that in your version of **kubernetes** it doesn't work any more:

> ```
> --port int     Default: 10251
> ```
>
> DEPRECATED: the port on which to serve HTTP insecurely without
> authentication and authorization. If 0, don't serve plain HTTP at all.
> **See --secure-port instead.**

`--secure-port` still can be specified:

> ```
> --secure-port int     Default: 10259
> ```
>
> The port on which to serve HTTPS with authentication and
> authorization. If 0, don't serve HTTPS at all.

Comment: That's right, it's deprecated but the documentation doesn't give clues on how to overwrite it. As such I moved to using an Admission Controller to mutate my deployments (Kyverno). I will add it as an alternative to the questions for future users.